# splitting an image in python

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I have a random input of size (H,W,C). I want to Split it into Z images of same size (224,224,3) where Z is a variable determined based on the image size. It does not matter if they are overlapping !
my goal is to process the subimages and then reconstruct the original one.
if anyone could help !

Comment: you want to split by `(H,W,C)` the original image into subimages?

Comment: My original image is of size (H,W,C). My goal is to croppit into overlapping patches of same size (224,224,3) and then after the processing I want to reconstruct the original image

Comment: what is that `C` constant, doesnt it have something to do with that `3`?

Comment: of course C is the number of channels which is equal to 3, the height and width are random

Comment: Splitting images in such a way is not that complicated, but for the reconstruction, it makes a difference, if the original image size is known for a set of subimages (overlap can be re-calculated on-the-fly, for example) or not (that might even involve image stitching).

Comment: Also, for the spliiting part, you might want to have a look at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58383814/how-to-divide-an-image-into-evenly-sized-overlapping-if-needed-tiles/58387766#58387766).

Answer (score 2):

For the splitting part, I will just reference [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58387766/11089932). Instead of saving the coordinates of each subimage in the final list, I saved the actual subimages there.

On the reconstruction part: If the reconstruction method knows the final (or original) image size, you can simply reconstruct the number of subimages in each direction and their corresponding overlaps; it's basically the same code as for the splitting. From that information, you can easily reconstruct the original image.

If the reconstruction method only gets a list of subimages, it'll get complicated! From my point of view, for arbitrary images (and, following, their subimages), you'll need advanced image stitching techniques.

Nevertheless, for images

1. which will be stored lossless (internally or externally), and
2. with "unique" overlapping areas,

I came up with the following idea:

- From the first two subimages you can brute-force search the first vertical overlap in the first column. That works, because the above splitting method saves subimages in that order, and because of the above two assumptions.
- Then, you can use that vertical overlap (or the decrement) to find the remainding subimages of the first column. That works, because the above splitting method guarantees the most equal overlap (within +/- 1), and the first vertical overlap in each column is always the larger one.

  - Now, when the end of the first column is reached, you won't find an appropriate vertical overlap with the next subimage, since it's the first image of the second row. Notice, that only works, if the above assumption 2. holds. Looking at the image in [alexzander's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66399833/11089932), this procedure will fail. The lower part of the last subimage of the first column (all zeros) is equal to the top part of the first subimage of the second column.
- When reached the end of the first column, we can determine the number of vertical overlaps, thus the number of subimages per column. From that, we also know the number of subimages per row. So, now, we do the whole thing again for finding the proper horizontal overlaps.
- Having all the horizontal and vertical overlaps, we can cut all subimages accordingly and stack them to reconstruct the original image.

Yes, that's a lot of work to do, but you don't need advanded image stitching, and I assume, that this reconstruction method will work for most real world images. Any large single-color backgrounds (in combination with small overlaps) or any compression between generating the subimages and reconstructing the original image will lead to malfunction.

Here's the full code:

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np


# Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58383814
def gen_subimages(image, hTile, wTile):

    h, w = image.shape[:2]

    # Number of tiles
    nTilesX = np.uint8(np.ceil(w / wTile))
    nTilesY = np.uint8(np.ceil(h / hTile))

    # Total remainders
    remainderX = nTilesX * wTile - w
    remainderY = nTilesY * hTile - h

    # Set up remainders per tile
    remaindersX = np.ones((nTilesX - 1), np.uint16) * \
                  np.uint16(np.floor(remainderX / (nTilesX - 1)))
    remaindersY = np.ones((nTilesY - 1), np.uint16) * \
                  np.uint16(np.floor(remainderY / (nTilesY - 1)))
    remaindersX[0:np.remainder(remainderX, np.uint16(nTilesX - 1))] += 1
    remaindersY[0:np.remainder(remainderY, np.uint16(nTilesY - 1))] += 1

    images = []

    # Determine proper tile boxes
    k = 0
    x = 0
    for i in range(nTilesX):
        y = 0
        for j in range(nTilesY):
            images.append(image[y:y+hTile, x:x+wTile, :])
            k += 1
            if j < (nTilesY - 1):
                y = y + hTile - remaindersY[j]
        if i < (nTilesX - 1):
            x = x + wTile - remaindersX[i]

    return images


def reconstruct_image(subimages):

    n_si = len(subimages)
    height, width = subimages[0].shape[:2]

    # VERTICAL OVERLAPS

    # Brute-force search for first vertical overlap
    y_overlaps = []
    for y in np.arange(height - 1, 1, -1):
        if np.all(subimages[0][y:, ...] == subimages[1][:-y, ...]):
            y_overlaps.append(height - y)
            break

    if len(y_overlaps) > 0:
        y_ol = y_overlaps[0]

        # Get following vertical overlaps
        for i in np.arange(1, n_si - 1):
            if np.all(subimages[i][height - y_ol:, ...] ==
                      subimages[i + 1][:y_ol, ...]):
                y_overlaps.append(y_ol)
            elif np.all(subimages[i][height - (y_ol - 1):, ...] ==
                        subimages[i + 1][:(y_ol - 1), ...]):
                y_ol -= 1
                y_overlaps.append(y_ol)
            else:
                break

    nTilesY = len(y_overlaps) + 1
    nTilesX = n_si // nTilesY

    # HORIZONTAL OVERLAPS

    # Brute-force search for first horizontal overlap
    x_overlaps = []
    for x in np.arange(width - 1, 1, -1):
        if np.all(subimages[0][:, x:, :] == subimages[nTilesY][:, :-x, :]):
            x_overlaps.append(width - x)
            break

    if len(x_overlaps) > 0:
        x_ol = x_overlaps[0]

        # Get following horizontal overlaps
        for i in np.arange(nTilesY, n_si - nTilesY, nTilesX):
            if np.all(subimages[i][:, width - x_ol:, :] ==
                      subimages[i + nTilesY][:, :x_ol, :]):
                x_overlaps.append(x_ol)
            elif np.all(subimages[i][:, width - (x_ol - 1):, :] ==
                        subimages[i + nTilesY][:, :(x_ol - 1), :]):
                x_ol -= 1
                x_overlaps.append(x_ol)
            else:
                break

    # Get all properly cutted subimages
    x_overlaps.insert(0, 0)
    y_overlaps.insert(0, 0)
    stacks = [subimages[iy + (ix * nTilesY)][y:, x:, ...]
              for iy, y in enumerate(y_overlaps)
              for ix, x in enumerate(x_overlaps)]

    # Stack cutted subimages
    image_recon = np.vstack([np.hstack(stacks[i:i + nTilesX])
                            for i in np.arange(0, nTilesX * nTilesY, nTilesX)])

    return image_recon


img = cv2.imread('path/to/your/image.png')

images = gen_subimages(img, 224, 224)
for im in images:
    print(im.shape)

img_recon = reconstruct_image(images)
print('Original image == Reconstructed image:', np.all(img == img_recon))
```

As usual, this is my test image:

[image: Paddington]

And, that's the output of the code:

```
(224, 224, 3)
(224, 224, 3)
(224, 224, 3)
(224, 224, 3)
Original image == Reconstructed image: True
```

You see, all subimages have the desired shape of `(224, 224, C)` and the reconstructed image is the same as the original image.

Comment: I think this technique is not working if you are doing some manipulations on tiles and that overlapping parts are not equal

Answer (score 1):

i used this image: (`original.png - (1280 x 640)`) and `PIL` lib, if that is convenient for you, instead of `cv2`.
[image: original image with python]

code

```py
import os
from PIL import Image

class SubImage(object):
    def __init__(self, pil_image, coordinates):
        # PIL image object
        self.img = pil_image
        # this is a list with coordinates
        # used to crop from the original image;
        # these coordinates must be used as
        # DIAGONAL in order to crop or put back in place
        self.coords = coordinates


def generate_sections(x_dim, y_dim, cut_x, cut_y):
    """ sections from 0 to X and 0 to Y with step by step
        step is the cut size
    """
    yy = []
    for y in range(0, x_dim, cut_x):
        yy.append(y)
    yy.append(x_dim)

    xx = []
    for x in range(0, y_dim, cut_y):
        xx.append(x)
    xx.append(y_dim)

    # lists of int tuples
    return xx, yy


def generate_crop_coordinates(xx, yy):
    """ every combination of pair with
        the values from above function
    """
    coords = []
    for x in xx:
        rows = []
        for y in yy:
            rows.append((x, y))
        coords.append(rows)
    return coords


def generate_subimages(coords: list):
    subimages = []
    for i in range(len(coords) - 1):
        row0 = coords[i]
        row1 = coords[i + 1]

        for ii in range(len(row0) - 1):
            x_pair, y_pair = row0[ii], row1[ii + 1]

            cropped = img.crop((x_pair[1], x_pair[0], y_pair[1], y_pair[0]))
            cropped_coords = [
                (x_pair[1], x_pair[0]),
                (y_pair[1], y_pair[0])
            ]
            subimg = SubImage(cropped, cropped_coords)
            subimages.append(subimg)

    # array of PIL Images
    return subimages


def get_dimensions(subimages: list):
    """ we need this for reconstruction
        because we dont know the original img size
        we only have the array of subimages
    """
    max_X = 0
    max_Y = 0
    for subimage in subimages:
        for coords in subimage.coords:
            # coords is a tuple
            max_X = coords[0] if coords[0] > max_X else max_X
            max_Y = coords[1] if coords[1] > max_Y else max_Y

    # max x and y are the size of image
    return max_X, max_Y


def reconstruct_image(subimages: list, folder: str):
    y, x = get_dimensions(subimages)
    new_image = Image.new("RGBA", (y, x))

    for subimage in subimages:
        new_image.paste(subimage.img, subimage.coords[0])

    # saves locally
    new_image.save(os.path.join(folder, "reconstructed.png"))
    return new_image


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # this is what you provide as user
    cut_size = (224, 224, 3)

    # and you provide the image, ofc
    original_path = "original.png"
    img = Image.open(original_path)
    img_size = img.size

    if cut_size[0] > img_size[0] or cut_size[1] > img_size[1]:
        raise ValueError("image size smaller than cut size.")

    xx, yy = generate_sections(*img_size, cut_size[0], cut_size[1])

    coords = generate_crop_coordinates(xx, yy)

    subimages = generate_subimages(coords)

    for index, subimage in enumerate(subimages, start=1):
        # -> if you want to save the pieces and see them
        subimage.img.save(f"{index}.png")
        # print(subimage.coords)

    folder = "."
    reconstruct_image(subimages, folder)
```

some pieces of the image: (`coordinates pairs`)

section 1: `[(0, 0), (224, 224)]`

section 2: `[(224, 0), (448, 224)]`

section 3: `[(448, 0), (672, 224)]`

[image: section 1]
[image: section 2]
[image: section 3]

okey, i think you got the idea.

after running the script:
 `i got the same image as original`

i know that is a lot of code for a question, but is the fastest solution that came up.

enjoy.

Comment: Your code doesn't meet the mentioned requirements: Running your code with the given example yields `12.png` with shape `(224, 160, 3)` and `18.png` with shape `(192, 160, 3)`. As stated in the question, ALL patches should have shape `(224, 224, 3)`, and they might overlap.

Comment: all the subimages cant have `(224, 224, 3)` because `1280 % 224 != 0` and `640 % 224 != 0`.